# How do I get rid of this strange box in my Excel Sheet

Tags: excel

I know that there must be a simple solution to this, but I don't even know what the box is called so I couldn't find the right answer on google.  If I hover over anything in the box, nothing pops up.  I can't right-click it either.

I can copy the entire sheet and paste values to a new sheet, and the box goes away, but if I include formatting the box comes back.

Below is a picture. Thank you for your help!

[image: Strange Excel Box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data Tab ---> Ungroup ---> Clear Outline

[image]

Comment: You are a savior!  The only bad thing about this is StackOverflow says I can't accept it as an answer for another 5 minutes.